# Zlib - определение гарантированного размера под Сжатые данные

Tags: c++, c, zlib

Подскажите пожалуйста:

Предположим есть некоторые данные, которая я хочу сжать с помощью Zlib.

Для примера я использую функции Zlib - compress/Compress2.

Для того, чтобы определить гарантированный размер выходного буфера, куда Zlib запишет сжатые данные - есть функция compressBound:

```
compressBound OF((uLong sourceLen));

 compressBound() returns an upper bound on the compressed size after
 compress() or compress2() on sourceLen bytes.  It would be used before a
 compress() or compress2() call to allocate the destination buffer.
```

Но, как и написано в описании к этой функции - она определяет гарантированный размер только при условии, что я использую для сжатия функции compress() или compress2().

А что, если я использую напрямую deflateinit и deflate? Как для этого случая определять гарантированный размер ?

Comment: пожалуй что не надо определять. вйона план покажет(ц) - deflate сжимает столько данных, сколько возможно и останавливается, когда входной буфер опустошается или когда переполнится выходной буфер.

Comment: @Sergey Tatarintsev, да ? Если война план покажет, то зачем тогда существует функция compressBound  ?

Comment: она нужна для другого. The compressBound() function ..... bytes of data using the compress() or compress2() functions